Vuetify v-overlay location-strategy="static", how make content to the bottom?
I want make v-card to the bottom of overlay, but prop 'location' dosen't change anything. (It's should be strategt="static" i think, i need menu in the same place from the bottom of screen.)
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-btn @click="showOverlay">click me</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="showOverlay">click me</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="showOverlay">click me</v-btn>
        <v-overlay v-model="overlay" location-strategy="static" location="bottom">
         <v-card style="width: 100vw">
          <v-card-text>
            <v-list class="d-flex">
              <v-list-item @click="hideOverlay">click me to hide</v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-overlay>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const overlay = ref(false)
  const showOverlay = () => {
    overlay.value = true
  }
  const hideOverlay = () => {
    overlay.value = false
  }
  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>


I try to make menu in the bottom of screen, but i can't change position of v-overlay content.
click me

check the docs to understand what location and location-strategy props are actually for.  they're not for your use case. You can solve this with normal CSS

see this playground
